# Why can I not edit my form's text field?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form that I'm using within Twitter Bootstrap 3. The form posts data to a mysql database and the placeholder values are echoed from the database. I have used a `<textarea>` input in the 'bio' field but for some reason the placeholder text behaves differently here. I can't drop a cursor and edit a particular word like I can with the other fields. Why is this?

```
<div class="form-group">
    <form class="" action="" id="edit_profile" method="post">
        <label>
                Name
              </label>
        <input id="user_name" name="user_name" type="text" placeholder="<?php echo $user_name ; ?>" value="<?php echo $user_name ; ?>" class="form-control input-md" required="">
</div>
Email
</label>
<input id="user_email" name="user_email" type="text" placeholder="<?php echo $user_email; ?>" value="<?php echo $user_email; ?>" class="form-control input-md" required="">
</div>

Bio
</label>

<textarea style="width:100%" value="<?php echo $bio; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $bio; ?>" name="bio"></textarea>
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['user_session'] ?>">

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-small btn-green pull-right" id="submit">

              Save
            </button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Textarea-text does not go in the `value=` it goes between the `<textarea><?php echo $bio; ?></textarea>` tags.

```html
<textarea placeholder="This is a placeholder">This is the actual text</textarea>
```

You cannot have a `value=` on a `<textarea>` since it will stay the same regardless of what you put inside the `<textarea>` and therefore won't change anything regardless of what you type. (Try removing the "This is the actual text" in the example)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I'm still unclear exactly what you mean. Like this? <input type="text" name="bio" value="<?php echo $bio; ?>" placeholder="<textarea><?php echo $bio;?></textarea>">